# Scala sum specific value of Seq of object

Tags: scala

let's say I have this:

```
case class AdResponse(data: Seq[InsightsData],paging: Paging)


case class InsightsData(impressions: String,
                        frequency: String,
                        objective: String,
                        spend: String    
                       )
```

And my response is `Seq[AdResponse]`

what's the best way to get the sum of all the spend in Scala? for each `AdResponse` and for `all`

Comment: `spend` is a `String`. How do you sum strings?

Comment: by conveting it to double `.toDouble`

Comment: `AdResponse` takes no type parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your question asks about tuples, but there are no tuples in your code. And, as Andrey Tyukin has pointed out, `Seq[AdResponse[Seq[InsightsData]]]` is not legal syntax for the data types in your code.

So I'm going to take a guess that you might be looking for something like this.

```
val arSums :Seq[Double] = myResponse.map(_.data.map(_.spend.toDouble).sum)
val total :Double = arSums.sum
```

Comment: you are right, my question is misleading I will fix it,